# How to mock.patch a function with itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to replace a function with itself, using different parameters.

Here is a sample. <sub><sup>I can't share the real code, I'm on papery secrecy!</sup></sub>

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import mymodule
import production

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @patch('production.mymodule.myfunction', lambda: mymodule.myfunction(devmode=True))
    def test_main_with_mymodule_function_does_not_raise_exception(self):
        # This is an integration test. myfunction is used within main.
        try:
            production.main()
        except Exception as e:
            self.fail(e)
```

As expected the following generates a recursive call:

```
@patch('production_code.mymodule.myfunction', lambda: mymodule.myfunction(devmode=True))
```

We basically decorate `myfunction` with a decorator that will call `myfunction`. We get a nice "Too many recursions" exception!

I need a way to replace `myfunction(devmode=False)` with `myfunction(devmode=True)`. But because I am in an integration test, and testing `main()`, I have no direct access to the function's parameters. Thing is, I made this very integration test to test how myfunction integrates with everything else in main.

Ideally, I shouldn't even have to create a `devmode` parameter, but I'm running a heavy sql query that requires to be limited by adding `"TOP(10)"` to the query.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the unpatched function before your test runs. Use that in the patch call:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


def iut(devmode=False):
    print(devmode)


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    _unpatched = iut   # keep reference to unpatched IUT

    @patch('so_test.iut', lambda *args, **kwargs: MyTest._unpatched(devmode=True))
    def test(self):
        try:
            iut()
        except Exception as e:
            self.fail(e)
```

This results in the following, indicating `devmode` was set to True:

```
True
```

Note: you might need to pass `args`, `kwargs` to `_unpatched` depending in your function.